# \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with \textsf: strange phenomenon

Tags: fonts, packages, font-encodings, sans-serif

I have some trouble using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`: `\textsf` text is no longer sans-serif. For instance,

```
{\Huge\textsf{\bfseries SOME TEXT some text}}
```

becomes

[image]

instead of the usual

[image]

I suppose there is something wrong between packages, but I cannot find the problem. **What should be done to recover the usual sans-serif text?** Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Please show us a compilable code we can copy and test on our computer. Then we can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you are using the `cm-super` fonts. Did you introduce the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` somewhere in your code? If it's the case, comment it out, or add `\usepackage{lmodern}`if you want to stick to the T1 font encoding.

Comment: Do you have the usual suspects included? `cmsuper` or `lmodern`?

Comment: I have seen the duplicate of karlkoeller. The first possibility of adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` has lead to some horrible phenomena in the formulas (changed symbols, I had never seen something like this). The second possibility, however, to use `\usepackage{fix-cm}`, has worked perfectly. Thank you very much to all four of you.

Comment: just a quibble ... the changed text is still sans serif.  it just isn't bold.